Redisson getMap returns an emtpy Custom object even though values were added to it
I am trying to retrieve a custom object that is added to the RMap but the returned object is empty. I am new to Redis and Redisson and unable to figure out the issue what I am missing.
I have a Custom Object MyCache which is as follows and can store any custom object:
    public class MyCache<T> implements Serializable {
        protected final Map<String, T> valueMap = new HashMap<String, T>();
        private final Set<CacheEventListener> cacheEventListeners = new HashSet<CacheEventListener>();
        protected final Map<String, Integer> cacheMinutesMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        // getters and setters
    }

I have another custom object Company:
    public class Company implements Serializable {
        private int id;
        private String code;
        private String name;

        // constructors, getters and setters
    }

I am storing instances of this class on the RMap as follows:
    Config redissonConfig = Config.fromYAML(new File(configPath));
    RMap<String, MyCache> cacheMap = Redisson.create(redissonConfig).getMap("my-redis-stack");
  
    Company company = new Company(1, "MC", "My Company");

    MyCache myCache = new MyCache();
    myCache.getValueMap().put("MC", company);

    cacheMap.fastPut("myCompanies", myCache); 

When I try to get this myCache object, RMap returns an empty object:
    Config redissonConfig = Config.fromYAML(new File(configPath));
    RMap<String, MyCache> cacheMap = Redisson.create(redissonConfig).getMap("my-redis-stack");

    cacheMap.get("myCompanies");  // returns an empty MyCache object

What am I doing wrong

Why are you using  myCache.getValueMap("MC", company); shouldnt it be like myCache.putValue("MC", company); and always shutdown redis client after its usage

Sorry that was typo. I have corrected it now.
